# Django - One CBV to handle multiple scenarios

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am having trouble to understand how to use a single CBV to handle (at least) 2 different scenarios. Here's what I am trying to do:

1. I have a ListView to display a list of objects. From there, I generate a link to navigate to
2. a DetailView to display the details of an object. From there, I generate a link to
3. a different view to render a related report.

I'd like to use the following URL's:

```
1. /myapp/list.html/
2. /myapp/detail.html/<<uuid>>/
3. /myapp/detail.html/<<uuid>>/?<layout>
```

Scenario 2 and 3 I am thinking to use a single CBV but I don't understand how to differentiate the scenarios. Can you advise what my urls.py and my views.py need to look like?

EDIT: at the same time, I will need to use two different templates (or somehow differentiate what to display in the template): if I am calling /myapp/detail.html/<>/ then I want to see the object details. if I am calling /myapp/detail.html/<>/? I want to render an iframe to display a corresponding report.

Thanks!

EDIT:

here's a click flow[image: click flow]

Answer (score 0):

For Django 2+ use path instead of `url` in `urls.py`

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
urlpatterns = [
    path('/myapp/list.html/', MyModelListView.as_view(), name="mymodel_list"),
    re_path(r'^/myapp/detail.html/(?P<uuid>[0-9a-f-]+)/(?P<layout>\w+)$', MyModelDetailView.as_view(), name="mymodel_detail"),
]
```

Views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

class MyModelListView(ListView):
    model = MyModel


class MyModelDetailView(DetailView):
    model = MyModel

    def get_queryset(self):
        layout = self.kwargs.get("layout", None)
        uuid = self.kwargs.get("uuid")
        # Your logic goes here
```

Comment: Thanks! When I do that, I get the following error:


`Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(UUID('ac987eb3-0aa9-4bc3-b2b1-404799f2a266'),)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['planning_detail.html/(?P<uuid>[0-9a-f-]+)/(?P<layout>\\w+)$']`

Comment: @DevKing did you try converting UUID to string?

Comment: Hi - how do you mean?